# Generics re: Scala.math.Ordering wrapper instance for java.lang.Comparable

Tags: scala, generics

I want to make a simple `Scala.math.Ordering` wrapper instance for `java.lang.Comparable`. I would think this is standard, but I don't see anything similar in JavaConversions.

Can someone get something like this to work:

`object ComparableOrdering[A <: Comparable[A]] extends Ordering[A] {
  def compare(a: A, b: A): Int = a.compareTo(b)
}`

Actually to handle classes like

`interface A {}
class B implements A, Comparable<A> {}`

it should be more like:

`object ComparableOrdering[A <: Comparable[B] with B] extends Ordering[A] {
  def compare(a: A, b: A): Int = a.compareTo(b)
}`

Can anyone get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard library already provides these instances via `Ordering.ordered`. For example, if you have a class like this:

```
class Foo(val i: Int) extends Comparable[Foo] {
  def compareTo(that: Foo): Int = this.i - that.i
}
```

You'll automatically have an instance available:

```
scala> Ordering[Foo].lt(new Foo(0), new Foo(1))
res0: Boolean = true
```

The signature of `Ordering.ordered` isn't quite the same as yours:

```
implicit def ordered[A](implicit arg0: (A) => Comparable[A]): Ordering[A]
```

This works because the standard library provides implicit "conversion" functions that will up-cast any type to any of its supertypes.

If for some reason you wanted to define your own instances, you could do something like this:

```
implicit def comparableOrdering[A <: Comparable[A]]: Ordering[A] =
  new Ordering[A] {
    def compare(a: A, b: A): Int = {
      println("Using custom instance for Comparable things")
      a.compareTo(b)
    }
  }
```

And then:

```
scala> Ordering[Foo].lt(new Foo(0), new Foo(1))
Using custom instance for Comparable things
res0: Boolean = true
```

I'd guess that the standard library doesn't define these instances this way for reasons related to implicit prioritization, but the instances for `Ordering` are a mess and the question of why they use the `A => Comparable[A]` approach probably isn't worth thinking too hard about.

Comment: That is what I need. I didn't see that. Can you get Ordering.ordered working with Java 8 LocalDateTime?

Comment: No, but you could for `ChronoLocalDate`.